# Mail - Deleting/Hiding Exchange mailbox's (e.g. RSS Feeds)

Tags: mail.app, exchange-activesync

We're running Exchange 2010 and I have access the server if I can make changes there.

Basically is there a way to hide or delete the RSS Feeds folder that shows up on the Mac Mail app?

When I try to delete it I get:

```
The mailbox “RSS Feeds” could not be deleted.
The server returned the error: Distinguished folders cannot be deleted.
```

You can't get rid of it from Outlook 2013 (Windows) either.

Any ideas?

I was hoping you could disable these folders from the Exchange backend but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to removed the RSS Feeds folder from Outlook 2013 using MFCMAPI
http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/
there's a youtube demo here as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g45GbCOjx0
Only difference with Outlook 2013 compared to Outlook 2010 in video was that the RSS folder was found in the the IPM_Subtree subfolder.